# How can I skip a non-accessible folder?

Tags: c#, exception, permissions, tree, directory

This is my recursive function:

```
private void createListFolder(string path)
{
    try
    {
        string[] directoryList = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
        if (directoryList.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (string directory in directoryList)
            {
                if (Directory.EnumerateFiles(directory).Any())
                {
                    folderList.Add(directory);
                }

                createListFolder(directory);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        txtErrors.AppendText(err.Message + Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```

that I call starting from the root path, read only folder with files and add the path to a list. The problem is that, if I catch a non-accessible folder, it stops. I just want to ignore non accessible folders (or better, get an exception, but still reading the rest of folders).

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a second try/catch in your loop (Nested try/catch statement), the error will be catched there and then the loop will resume.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below it will help you...

```
try
{
 createListFolder(directory);
}
catch (Exception err)
{
 txtErrors.AppendText(err.Message + Environment.NewLine);
}
```